# PGDATA equivalence for MySQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql, migration

Is there an equivalence of ($)PGDATA (Postgres) for MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you need, but `datadir` points to physical database files:

```
mysql> show variables like 'datadir';
+---------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name | Value           |
+---------------+-----------------+
| datadir       | /var/lib/mysql/ | 
+---------------+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

PGDATA contains :
Item        Description 
PG_VERSION  A file containing the major version number of PostgreSQL 
base        Subdirectory containing per-database subdirectories 
global      Subdirectory containing cluster-wide tables, such as pg_database 
pg_clog         Subdirectory containing transaction commit status data 
pg_multixact    Subdirectory containing multitransaction status data (used for shared row locks) 
pg_subtrans     Subdirectory containing subtransaction status data 
pg_tblspc   Subdirectory containing symbolic links to tablespaces 
pg_twophase     Subdirectory containing state files for prepared transactions 
pg_xlog         Subdirectory containing WAL (Write Ahead Log) files 
postmaster.opts   A file recording the command-line options the postmaster was last started with 
postmaster.pid  A lock file recording the current postmaster PID and shared memory segment ID (not present after postmaster shutdown)